# Setting timezone in AIX

Tags: unix, aix

The timezone is set to "CET" but `date` displays CEST

```
$ echo TZ
CET
$ date
Tue Apr 16 15:56:57 CEST 2013
```

Noticed the timezone on another similar system is "CET0" (not sure what the 0 means here!). But `date` displays the expected timezone:

```
$ echo $TZ
CET0
$ date
Tue Apr 16 15:51:26 CET 2013
```

So changed the timezone using `chtz CET0` and rebooted. But `date` now displays UTC!

```
$ echo $TZ
CET0
$ date
Tue Apr 16 13:49:39 UTC 2013
```

Whats going on? How to set the timezone on AIX correctly?

Comment: CET == Central European Time, CEST == Central European Savings Time during the (approximately) "not winter" months... Not sure what CET0 is...

Comment: @twalberg: surprisingly it's called Central European *Summer* Time, even though the S in DST means Saving :)

Comment: Best option: `TZ=Europe/YourCapital` if it doesn't work (old AIX, incomplete timezone-database): `TZ=CET-1CEST-2,M3.5.0/2,M10.5.0/3`. Nonetheless, you can 'deactivate' DST, if you set `TZ=CET-1CET-1`

Answer (score 2):

Does your AIX install have the **smitty** package?
Navigate through the menus:
System Environments -> Change/Show Date and Time -> Change Time Zone Using System Defined Values
Find whatever timezone is closest to you. I'm in America/New_York